# calculate limit of $a_{n+1}=e^{-a_n}$

Tags: limits

I have proven that $e^{-x}=x$ have only one solution in $(0,1)$.

How do I prove that $a_{n+1}=e^{-a_n}$, ($a_0=1$) converge to that solution?

Comment: Use Banach's fix-point-theorem

Comment: how do I prove that $|e^{-x}-e^{-y}|<|x-y| \forall{x,y}\in (0,1)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $L $ be the unique root.

then

$$|a_n-L|=|e^{-a_{n-1}}-e^{-L} |$$
$$=|a_{n-1}-L|e^{-c} $$